# Launching Java Executable using Command Prompt / Terminal - Batch/Shell/Command files

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, command

I was curious to see how I can supply users with a batch/shell/command file to open my Java executable jar file.

For example,

`launch-windows.bat` launches the Java application on a windows machine

`launch-linux.sh` launches the Java application on a linux machine

`launch-mac.command` launches the Java application on macOS machine

These files would be in the same directory as the JAR file.

Edit:
I have this working for Windows PC, a similar issue is not working for mac...

Inside of the batch file only yields this:

`java -jar myJar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing launcher scripts for potential users of your app. You can't make a lot of assumptions regarding their environment configurations. If something is off - you have to give the user an error message with an explanation - what is wrong.

Usually in such scripts there are some checks before execution of the app to ensure that all prerequisites are fulfilled. For java applications you have to check if there is a java installation at all :)

Windows script for example:

```
IF "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
        ECHO "ERROR: Java home is not set"
        EXIT /B
        )

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar myJar.jar
```

Shell script for example:

```sh
if [ -n `which java` ]; then
  echo "Java found"
else
  echo "Java NOT found!"
  exit 1
fi

exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar myJar.jar
```

Using `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to provide path to java binaries is sort of a standard. Maven, for example, uses it.
Those scripts ensure that this variable configured and in case if its not provided - user will be informed.

In a similar way perform checks for other prerequisites to execute your application.

P.S I have no experience of usage mac, but I assume that shell script will work there somehow.